# Leaflet slider - custom looks

Tags: jquery, leaflet, jquery-plugins

Has anyone ever tried to change the looks (**length**, **thickness**) of the [Leaflet plugin LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider)?
It is based on JQuery.

Here is where I initialize it:

```
sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
    position: "topright",
    layer: testlayer,
    range: true
});


myMap.addControl(sliderControl);

sliderControl.startSlider();
$('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 19));
```

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] to include a [mcve] of a specific issue.